# Obtener los ids o names de campos dinamicos con Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy realizando un sistema de compras y ventas, en el cual utilizo multiples items para el mismo, utilizo una paquete(gema) que me permite agregar dichos campos dinamicos llamada: "Cocoon" es un paquete para el framework de Ruby On Rails, sin embargo, genera ids y names automaticos, el cual se me dificulta extraer, la situasión que estoy validando mis campos con Jquery-validation, de que forma, podria obtener los ids o names en este caso, independientemente del numero de item que sea, y verifique si esta en blanco o no, la verificación lo hago con el codigo de abajo, pero al no poder tener el "name" dinamico del campo se me dificulta poder validar dichos campos dinamicos.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        "product[code]": {
        required: true, maxlength: 32, normalizer: function(value) { return $.trim(value); }
        },
        "product[name]": {
        required: true, maxlength: 32, normalizer: function(value) { return $.trim(value); }
        },
    },
    messages: {
        "product[code]": { required: "El campo es requerido", maxlength: "No se permiten mas de 32 caracteres" },
        "product[name]": { required: "El campo es requerido", maxlength: "No se permiten mas de 32 caracteres" },
    }
    });
});
```

El codigo anterior validaria los mensajes de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver en la imagen, para el campo de price, genera el siguiente name: "input_input_items_attributes_1534806645872_price", el cual "1534806645872" es generado aleatoriamente, o como una especie de timestamp, ese name, deberia poder colocarlo dentro de las reglas y mensajes a validar e el campo, y poder ponerlo como:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        "input_input_items_attributes_XXXXX_price": {
        required: true, maxlength: 32, normalizer: function(value) { return $.trim(value); }
    },
    messages: {
        "input_input_items_attributes_XXXXX_price": { required: "El campo es requerido", maxlength: "No se permiten mas de 32 caracteres" },
    }
    });
});
```

En conclusión, es poder obtener el id de forma dinamica, y que Jquery pueda leerlo para validar el item, independientemente del name que tenga, agradezco muchisimo su ayuda!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Podrias iterar sobre todos los inputs y agregar las reglas.  Si tienes diferentes reglas para diferentes inputs, podrias agregar clases y hacerlo de la misma manera.  Algo asi:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var rules = {};
    var messages = {};
    $('#form input').each(function(i, input) {
        rules[$(input).attr('id')] = { required: true, maxlength: 32, normalizer: function(value) { return $.trim(value); };
        messages[$(input).attr('id')] = { required: "El campo es requerido", maxlength: "No se permiten mas de 32 caracteres" };
    });
    $("#form").validate({
        rules: rules,
        messages: messages
    });
});
```

Comment: Saludos Alanfcm, he adaptado el codigo de esa manera, pero no sucede nada, no valida los campos, no se si lo he modificado correctamente?,

Comment: La forma en que lo hiciste es incorrecta.  Ya edite mi respuesta, solo tienes que copiar y pegar.

Comment: El codigo va perfecto Alanfcm, sin embargo, aunque me condiciona todos los campos del formulario, no lo hace con los dinamicos, acabo agregar una imagen al final del post, de como se ve el resultado de tu codigo, no se que podria faltar para que los tome en cuenta? Por cierto, como dato curioso, no me funciona con 'id', solo con 'name'

Comment: Me imagine que validas cuando haces click en algun boton.  Intenta mover este codigo al handler de dicho boton.

Comment: Te refieres a agregarlo dentro de la misma pagina del formulario, o agregar un id o algo que represente a dicho submit

Comment: Puedes agregar un click handler al boton "Agregar producto" o puedes agregar el handler "submit" de tu formulario.